# TypeScript: Type boolean is not assignable to type true (or false) using two interfaces

Tags: typescript, interface

if I'm using some code like the below, I would expect TypeScript to be able to infer that `badObj` is an acceptable argument for `fn`, because it must of type `Bad`.

In fact, in the body of `fn` it sees no issue, but at the invocation `fn(badObj)` it renders the error in the comment at the bottom. Same goes for `fn(goodObj)`.

How can I improve this code to work like I'm expecting?

```
interface Ok {
    ok: true;
    date: undefined;
}

interface Bad {
    ok: false;
    date: Date;
}

const badObj = { ok: false, date: new Date()};
const goodObj = { ok: true, date: undefined}

const fn = (obj: Ok | Bad) => {
    console.log(obj.ok);

    if (!obj.ok) {
        const minutes = obj.date.getMinutes();
    }
};

fn(badObj)
fn(goodObj)

/*
The following error is thrown on the invocation of `fn(badObj)` and `fn(goodObj)`

Argument of type '{ ok: boolean; date: Date; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Ok | Bad'.
 Type '{ ok: boolean; date: Date; }' is not assignable to type 'Bad'.
    Types of property 'ok' are incompatible.
      Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.(2345)
*/
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const badObj = { ok: false, date: new Date()};
```

Since you havn't given this an explicit type, typescript will take its best guess at inferring the type. It comes up with `{ ok: boolean, date: Date }`. That's a pretty good guess, but it erases the fact that `ok` is specifically a `false`. So later, when you try to pass it into `fn`, typescript thinks that `ok` might be `true`, which would not be allowed when paired with a date. `goodObj` has a similar problem, just with the opposite values.

You have several options for fixing this. Option 1 is to give the objects explicit types, so that `ok` should be treated as `false` instead of `boolean`:

```
const badObj: Bad = { ok: false, date: new Date()};
```

Or you can give typescript a hint to change how it infers the type. With `as const`, typescript will assume that the contents of the object will never change, and as such it will assume the strictest possible type:

```
const badObj = { ok: false, date: new Date() } as const;
// type is: 
// {
//    readonly ok: false;
//    readonly date: Date;
// }
```

Or if you're on typescript 4.9 or later, you can use the new `satisfies` operator. Similar to as const, it will infer the type more strictly (minus the readonly part), but it will also verify that your object matches the `Bad` type, and give you an error if it does not:

```
const badObj = { ok: false, date: new Date() } satisfies Bad;
// type is:
// {
//    ok: false;
//    date: Date;
//}
```